# Printing a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c++

This may be very simple but I am confused! 
I am getting segmentation fault when extracting information from a pointer to a pointer. See the cout section in main(). Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks..

Sen

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef struct{
  int hour;
  int minute;
} Time;

Time* GetNextTime(void)
{
 Time *p_time = new Time;
 return p_time;  
}

void GetTime( Time **sometime )
{
 int length = 10;
 sometime = new Time*[length];
 for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
 {
    sometime[i] = GetNextTime();
    sometime[i]->hour = rand()%24 ;
    sometime[i]->minute = rand()%60;
    std::cout << "Entered times " << sometime[i]->hour << " hour " << sometime[i]->minute << " minutes " << std::endl;
  }
}


int main()
{
  Time** _time;
  GetTime( _time );

 //here is the question
 // I cant print them from original _time
  for( int i=0; i<10; i++)
  std::cout <<  " Print times " << (*_time)[i].hour << " hour " << (*_time)[i].minute << " minutes " << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a two star pointer in the first place?

Comment: Is it giving you an error at runtime?  Whats the error message or the result?

Comment: Please do not tag as C questions that are about C++.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing `sometime` by value, not by reference so it remains uninitialized.  Change `GetTime` to the following:

```
void GetTime( Time ** &sometime ) //& means pass by reference
```

Because you're creating an array of pointers, you can use array notation to access them during printing as well.

```
std::cout <<  " Print times " << _time[i]->hour << " hour "
          << _time[i]->minute << " minutes " << std::endl;
```

Comment: Probably worth adding that your code is not exception safe and you do leak memory (160 bytes on my system).  A better solution is probably to go with std::vector (as Dietmar Khul recommended in his answer).

Answer (score 2):

Unless an argument is explicitly labelled as using a reference it is passed by value in C++. Thus, assigning to `sometime` in `GetTime()` has no effect on `_time` in `main()`.

My strong advice is **not** to us explict memory allocation but use containers, e.g. `std::vector<T>`, instead. You'd still need to pass the container by refernence, however.

Answer (score 1):

In `main`

It should be

`Time *_time;`

`GetTime(&_time)`

And then `cout` should be done with `_time` instead of `*_time`